# Is there any solution to see problems in rendering pages (performance problems) in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, performance, angular-material, render

I got a simple thing to render big JSON data (file got about 2-3mb) to HTML directly. 
What am I doing?

1. Getting data from API
2. Parse it to as `this.obj = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)`;
3. Append it to HTML as `{{ obj }}`

I just got such a big performance problem. This obj is rendering for 50-90 seconds. I was trying the same thing in pure javascript or even with Empty Angular Project and it takes about 2 seconds...
I was checking that is data is already downloaded and this does not issue with API - and it's not. Data is already there, but I still waiting such a big-time to render it.

What is the technology stack?

1. Angular Material
2. Angular 9

What is used in this issue?

1. Simple component with onPush strategy
2. Material UI TAB

I send you a SS from the performance tab:
[image]

Can you help me with that? I'm not good at checking performance and how to improve it. I created same sample on stackblitz - but render time was much much smaller... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to run your app with `ng serve --prod`
The difference between development and production mode is that in development mode, Angular 2 starts change detection immediately after the first run and logs a value has changed after it was checked error if anything changes between the first and second run. This helps locate bugs.

Comment: @BartoszTermena Currently I got an error which I saying:
`An invalid configuration file was found ['angular.json']. Please delete the file before running the command.` Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @Restir Have you isolated the part that is causing the bottleneck? Try removing the HTML, and then try removing the `JSON.stringify`, and then try rendering with the `json` pipe. I'm not sure there's a generic answer when it comes to optimising performance.

Comment: I've got a problem with that rendering issue. It was connected with styling. In this project, I've got lots of custom styles, which set dynamically the height of generated JSON and it provides a problem. Thank you for your help!